# How to turn off unsupported Google Play Service prompt in react-native app

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services, huawei-mobile-services

I added react-native-maps which running with Google maps to my project. On Huawei devices without GMS (Google Mobile Services) when app starts, I get this prompt:

[image]

How to disable this confirmation dialog on devices without GMS? (prefer this answer)

Or

Is there any workaround to install `react-native-maps` on GMS and `@hmscore/react-native-hms-map` on HMS and import it in a proper way (depends on device GMS/HMS core) as a module to javascript side ?

Comment: Have you seen: [Will react native work without Google Services on Huawei phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58631362/295004)

Answer (score 2):

GMS is not supported on Huawei phones released after the Google ban.

Here I provide three options for you:

**Option 1**: Release your app both on HUAWEI AppGallery and Google Play, with different packages. The app you release on AppGallery contains only Huawei's logic code. For details about multi-channel packaging, please refer to [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-config-flavor#h1-1580895408662?ha_source=hms1).

**Option 2**: Release the same app on HUAWEI AppGallery and Google Play. Add the following code to determine whether GMS APIs or HMS APIs are available and call the available APIs:

```
public boolean  isGMS(){
    return GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}
public boolean  isHMS(){
    return HuaweiApiAvailability.getInstance().isHuaweiMobileServicesAvailable(this) == com.huawei.hms.api.ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}
```

You can add the code manually, or use [HMS ToolKit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/huawei-toolkit/?ha_source=hms1) to realize G+H logic judgment.

**Option 3**：
if you just want to suppress this dialog complaining "No google services available in this device...." in RN that could be achieved by Turning off Google Play Services availability errors:

```
firebase.utils().errorOnMissingPlayServices = false;
firebase.utils().promptOnMissingPlayServices = false;
```

for more information please visit this [link](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting/android.md#turning-off-google-play-services-availability-errors).

Comment: But this confirmation dialog is caused by react-native-maps which uses Google under the hood. 
When I added in index.js :

import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app';
firebase.utils().errorOnMissingPlayServices = false;
firebase.utils().promptOnMissingPlayServices = false;

nothing was changed. 
Confirmation dialog still appears.

Comment: hi@karolkarp,have you check this **[link](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting/android.md#turning-off-google-play-services-availability-errors)**?It said that *This must be called at the module scope, outside any classes, preferably before any other usages of react-native-firebase so that it's disabled before the internal logic takes over.*

Comment: Yes, I call it before any other usages of react-native-firebase. Still confirmation dialog is showing up.